# Lookup multiple values in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a way for excel formulas to look up multiple values in an 2d matrix for excel? For example:

```
sum(vlookup({2015,2016},Matrix,{2,4,6},False)) = 3 + 4 + 5 + 2 + 3 + 2 

2014  1    3    7    11   9    2
2015  3    6    4    12   5    8
2016  2    1    3    99   2    6
```

I don't necessarily have to use the function vlookup but I prefer not having to use the same function multiple times then summing them since the list {2015,2016} could be quite long.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put your search criteria in one cell each:

[image]

Then use this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$1:$A$3,J1))*ISNUMBER(SEARCH(COLUMN($B$1:$G$3),K1))*$B$1:$G$3)
```

[image]

---

If you want to hard code the numbers then you can do it this way:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$1:$A$3,"2015,2016"))*ISNUMBER(SEARCH(COLUMN($B$1:$G$3),"2,4,6"))*$B$1:$G$3)
```

Comment: I like it a lot and it really works well with the Excel columns to look in actually corresponding to the matrix/table columns.  If the table's upper left cell was say in C4, there would need to be a column adjustment factor added to make the column number relative to the data table, not just the excel sheet location.  I think that is clear as mud and I am talking in circles now.

Answer (score 2):

I like @ScottCraner's answer a lot, I just did it slightly differently, but using close-on the same tricks.

For me, I put the year values in as follows in column N:

```
N1 = 2015
N2 = 2016
```

And the columns I wanted to use for the look-up in column O:

```
O1 = 2
O2 = 4
O3 = 6
```

Then, I used the following (**entered as an array formula** - meaning you press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER after putting it in):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1:A3,$N$1:$N$2,0))*ISNUMBER(MATCH(COLUMN(A1:G3)-COLUMN(A1)+1,$O$1:$O$3,0))*A1:G3)
```

Again, Scott's answer is perfectly right, I just added in a different way to get to the same result.

Hope it helps you or someone else facing the same kind of challenge.

Comment: I don't think it needs to be entered with CSE.  I have been playing with it and it works fine without.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. `-COLUMN(A1)+1` is nothing but `-1+1` which is always `0`, so can be removed from the formula.

Comment: @ScottCraner, cool!! - I truly didn't even try it without... Great check!

Comment: @Mrig, you are correct. The reason why I did that was so as to allow for the range to not begin in Column A. This formula would work for a range anywhere in a worksheet.